# How to avoid Firebase AuthListener to be triggered twice?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I successfully implemented Firebase anonymous authentication and Google. I also provide the user the possibility to sign-out. I also have implemented a FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener, to be notified when user state changes. If I sign-out from Google, the listener is called once. However, when using the exact same code to sign-out an anonymous user, the listener is called twice. Is the normal behavior? How to avoid this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {
    @Inject FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Basic stuff
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_sign_out) {
            singOutFirebase();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void singOutFirebase() {
        auth.signOut();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        auth.addAuthStateListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(this);
    }
}
```

When I sign-out the anonymous account, I get `onAuthStateChanged` printed two times. In case of Google, only one time.

Comment: Hi, I would be glad to help, but can you show the code? And the stack trace/logcat when the app runs? I may be able to see what's the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @FEBRYANASAPERDANA I'm only calling `FirebaseAuth.getInsance().signOut();` on a button click and inside the implemented `onAuthStateChanged` method, I only have a log statement that is triggered twice in case of the anonymous authentication and ONLY once in case of Google.

Comment: @LisDya Show us the code, instead of describing it please. You can add it to the question by clicking the `edit` link under it. "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: @FEBRYANASAPERDANA Please check my code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Please check my code.

Comment: @LisDya alright, I put on what I am thinking on this into answer and you can comment further on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put some check when the user is  signed out/signed in, and log from there. You could perform a check like this in your onAuthStateChanged listener callback:

```
if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {   
   Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged - User are signed out.");
} else if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
   Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged - User are signed in.");
}
```

Though I did not test it right now due to limited time, I think it'll work since it will serve itself as a gateway to prevent multiple logs from being printed. You can comment on my answer if it didn't work:)

There are also other discussions on other platform (aside from Android, such as React/React Native) that onAuthStateChanged are called twice or more when using anonymous account. I am not sure if this is normal behavior or not, but I think what you're thinking is right - it looks like something is wrong since the listener should be notified for only ONE event - either they sign in or sign out.

You can also possibly check in other codes as well to see if you are adding other AuthStateListener, since AFAIK and based on other discussions I found on this forum and Github, it may results in conflicts.

Do you have any Application class/module within your app?
You can set the AuthStateListener there, and create a static member inside that Application class to contain the instance/object of your Application, so you can access the listener from anywhere. Since you are setting AuthStateListener in the Application class, there is no need to add any more listeners to any activity/fragment. Just use the global AuthStateListener.

Anyway, you could also make your AuthStateListener reentrant/idempotent. This means that you keep track/bookkeep the value, be it a Int-based counter or a boolean value to know if the AuthStateListener has been called or not, and enable you to listen only for one specific event - sign in, or sign out. like this:

```
 private boolean hasAuthListenerBeenCalled = false
 // other code
 @Override
 public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
    if (hasAuthListenerBeenCalled) {
       // this auth state listener has already been called, ignore/omit any code 
       // execution or logging.
    } else {
       //has not been called yet, perform some code execution/logging.
       Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged");
    }
}
```

In any case, if this is not something you need to avoid so bad, then you can safely ignore this, especially if you are trying to log something, but if you are going to perform some code execution/computation, yes, it will be some problem.

Hope that helps and sorry for the long answer.
Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try your approach now, voted-up.

Comment: Good luck, don't hesitate to comment/ask if you need further help :)